# Add a row to a tibble consisting of strings and numbers

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble with 82 columns of which the first one is a character string and the rest are numbers. Here a small example with only 3 columns:

```
df <- df=tibble(agg = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),
x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1))
```

I want to add an additional row, where I have a vector with numeric values and a string

```
"k", c(1:2)
```

If there are only 3 columns, I can just use add_row(agg = "k", x1 = 1, x2 = 2), but with 83 columns this is not feasible. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
Renger

Comment: Are the values of the numeric columns important? If not you could do `rbind(c("k", rep(1, ncol(df) - 1)), df)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector and `rbind` it to original dataframe.

```
df1 <- rbind(c("k", 1:2), df)
df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)
df1

# A tibble: 11 x 3
#   agg      x1    x2
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 k         1     2
# 2 a         1     1
# 3 b         0     1
# 4 c         0    NA
# 5 d        NA     1
# 6 e         0     1
# 7 f         1     0
# 8 g         1    NA
# 9 h        NA    NA
#10 i         0     0
#11 j         1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `list` and `list` can have elements with multiple types, `rbind` (or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`) the `list`

```
rbind(df, list("k", 1, 2))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
#   agg      x1    x2
# * <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1     1
# 2 b         0     1
# 3 c         0    NA
# 4 d        NA     1
# 5 e         0     1
# 6 f         1     0
# 7 g         1    NA
# 8 h        NA    NA
# 9 i         0     0
#10 j         1     1
#11 k         1     2
```

---

Or using `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, list(agg = "k", x1 = 1, x2 = 2))
```

NOTE: Here, we don't have to change the types later